# Triangle mapping to triangle geometric construction

Tags: mobius-transformation

What  Moebius  transformation

$$ w=R \, \frac {z-p}{z-q}$$

sends a given equilateral triangle  $abc$ to another one $ABC$ in the plane ?

Since their circum=circles can be inter-mapped through these three invariants of Mobius mapping, how to make a geometric construction using the property?

Comment: The other one needs to be equilateral too?

Comment: I don't see why equilateral is relevant. Just solve 
$$w(a) = A,\;w(b)=B,\;w(c)=C$$
for $R,p,q$ (3 equations, 3 unknowns).

Comment: Just changed the post. Interested in a geometric construction actually.